# odoo override group permission on object

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, rules

I have a task in odoo 8, i have to create a user group named ( picker ) which will be in inheritance to warehouse user group. as Warehouse  Manager -> User --> test. so i created the user as follows :

```xml
<record id="warehouse_picker" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">picker </field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_warehouse_management"/>
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]" />
 </record>
```

also i have added this code to give access of menu warehouse to this user :

```xml
<record id="stock.group_stock_user" model="res.groups">
     <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('warehouse_picker')),(4, ref('stock.group_locations'))]"/>
</record>
```

Now, The Group Warehouse / User has access rule to an object (stock.picking) as 1,1,1,1. I need to restrict / Override this rule (stock.picking) to 1,0,0,0

I tried following code, but doesn't work :

```xml
<record id="warehouse_picker_rule" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Warehouse Picker Rule</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="stock.model_stock_picking"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[(1, '=', 1)]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('warehouse_picker'))]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>
</record>
```

Can someone help me to solve / override the existing rule. i don't want to touch the core module rules.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out from which module this rule is coming from and then you can override like:

```xml
<record id="module.rule_id" model="ir.model.access">
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
</record>
```

For example, module is stock and rule_id (you can find this with debug mode in the GUI or look into the modules ir.model.access.csv first column) is move_read_all:

```xml
<record id="stock.move_read_all" model="ir.model.access">
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
</record>
```

If i understand your wish correct, then you have to override it the following way:

```xml
<record id="stock.access_stock_picking_user" model="ir.model.access">
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
</record>
```

You will need to put the dependency to stock into your manifest file of your custom module.

Comment: Hi CZoellner, I did not find rule move_read_all in stock. moreover there is no column value as move_read_all in  ir.model.access.csv. Can you please guide me how to look using debug mode.

Comment: It was just an simple example. I tried to find your explicit access rule. First with ir.model.access.csv in module stock (stock/security/ir.model.access.csv). Searching for model_stock_picking found 2 entries and `access_stock_picking_user,stock.picking user,model_stock_picking,stock.group_stock_user,1,1,1,1` is the one you want. The first column holds the xml id (or external id) and is `access_stock_picking_user`.

Comment: Finding it by GUI is a bit tricky. You need to activate debug. Go to Settings/Technical/Security/Access Controls List and search for model stock.picking. You will find some entries. Now mark the one you want the xml id for and then switch to form view (right upper). Now open the debug menu and look for "view log" or something with meta data. On that popup you will get the xml id.

Comment: What odoo version do you use exactly? I was searching the xml id on Odoo V7

Comment: It is the same xml id in Odoo 8.

Comment: Hi CZoellner, Can you please tell me that is there a way that the override can be done on specific user group. I mean suppose the user is in  "warehouse_picker" group, then it overrides the access. but if the user is in other group, let's say "warehouse_receiver" group, then it do not override.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114325/discussion-between-czoellner-and-user280960).

Comment: @CZoellner: Hi, did you find the solution if I have to override existing group permission for two different groups. Kindly let me know.

Comment: the most ir.access.rule entries are related to a group. you have to find the these rules by yourself and then override it like the way in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing, create one csv file named "ir.model.access.csv" and into that create one record.

This csv file must contain following columns.

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink       
access_id,access_name,model_stock_picking,group_name_external_id,1,0,0,0
```

And add this to the **openerp**.py file, so it will set this access rights for the particular model to particular group. And suppose you want to set this permissions for all then just leave blank **"group_id"** fields then it will set this default permission for all users.

Comment: Thanks Emipro Technologies Pvt. Ltd.

Comment: Hi Emipro, Works great for access rule in own module , but if you need to override other groups access rule, this does not work. For Example, warehouse picker ( create rule on stock.picking) depends on two factor, 1) stock.picking access rule 2) if user is in Sales/see own leads group. So to disable need to override both. First is fine as it is sub group of warehouse/user. BUT for second it creates the access rule but not overrides it. I used following line in csv :  access_stock_picking_salesman,stock_picking salesman,stock.model_stock_picking,base.group_sale_salesman,1,1,0,0.

Comment: Once you set this rule and after that from any other module you again set rule for that group it will override this permissions. There is no matter whether you set rule by external  id or by csv similarly it will be overwritten if it will be there in any other module which will install later than this module. And I am not getting any difference between my and @CZoellner answer. The rule which will execute last by any module install/upgrade process will be applied for access rights.

Comment: Hi Emipro, When i overrided the rule in csv, it created new rule as below          stock_picking salesman   Sales / See own Leads   1,1,0,0    but it also have the previous rule defined by the system as below                                             stock_picking salesman  Sales / See own Leads  1,1,1,0                                  i mean it has both the rules, hence this does not work to override.

Comment: did you tried with the same id (id is external_id as like "stock.access_stock_picking_user") ?

Comment: I tried with same id as :          stock.access_stock_picking_salesman,stock_picking salesman,stock.model_stock_picking,base.group_sale_salesman,1,1,0,0    but the result is same : two entries        original ( stock_picking salesman Picking List Sales / See Own Leads 1,1,1,0 ) and newly created ( stock_picking salesman Picking List Sales / See Own Leads   1,1,0,0 )